# initiate data with async data in vue nuxt

Tags: asynchronous, vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js

I have a vue-nuxt component and want to initially set the data-(property) of my component with the data which I loaded by an asyncData API call.

```
data () {
  return {
    selected_company: this.contracts.company1.id *--> this gives me an undefined value*
  }
},
async asyncData({ app }) {
  const contracts = await app.$axios.$get("/companies/contracts")
return {contracts}
```

In my template I am able to access the data with the following code (therefore the data is successfully loaded):

```
{{this.contracts.company1}}
```

Since I have multiple entries in "contracts" I want to display them (e.g. in a dropdown) and capture the selected company with v-model. For some reasons I need to set an initial value for my "selected_company"-attribute.
This is a simplified example (my data structure is more complex and consists for example of nested elements).

How can I set an initial value for the data-properties e.g "selected_company" based on the result of a asyncData-call?
Do I miss something important or is there no easy-way for that?

Any help is highly appreciated! thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing the initial value inside the data property, you can try to add it in the created method.

```
created () {
  this.selected_company = this.contracts.company1.id
}
```

Or if it still doesn't work, try to add it to your watch property.

```
watch: {
  contracts: {
    handler (val) {
       this.selected_company = val.company1.id
    },
    deep: true
  }
}
```